# Speed fix or alternatives in lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-lambda-edge

I have a lambda@edge running on a client request. I'm dropping messages into SQS to be processed by another lambda.

The first run of my script after an update is extremely long - often blowing through the five second hard timeout, which is not a good user experience.

The majority of this is loading the AWS SDK, consistently above 2.5 seconds

```
var timerstart = new Date();
var timercheck = new Date();
console.log("Time check: 0");

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

timercheck = new Date();
console.log("Time check - AWS sdk loaded: ", timercheck - timerstart);
```

I'm also loading https

```
const https = require('https');
```

which takes about 120ms the first run.

Many subsequent runs are entirely completed sub-millisecond, few exceed 5ms.

Has anyone else had this issue - and hopefully found a way to overcome it? I'm not finding anything via googlefu. An understanding of the disparity between first run and subsequent runs would be helpful.

**Crazy idea**

@jogold lead to some interesting reading.

For some reason, I thought it would be interesting to place the require outside the export.

From:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    //... stuff
```

To:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    //... stuff
```

The first time check is now down to about 300ms over the several (pretty certain) cold starts. Perhaps this is just something everyone else knows about and a gap in my knowledge of NodeJS, but if anyone else comes looking for issues with Lambda@Edge execution times, here ya go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *Cold Start*.

Have a look at [Everything you need to know about cold starts in AWS Lambda](https://hackernoon.com/cold-starts-in-aws-lambda-f9e3432adbf0).

If it's critical you should consider prewarming your functions.